# How to receive get parameters from url in struts2

Tags: java, struts-1, seo, struts2

I am using struts2 & configured so the url will look like as
www.myweb.com/index instead of www.myweb.com/index.action

But now the problem i am facing is how should i map in struts.xml file & get request parameters
as in struts1 i can receive it through mapping.getParameters() but what available in struts2 for this?

```
<action path="/profile/*"
type="net.viralpatel.struts.cleanurl.ProfileAction"
parameter="{1}">
<forward name="success" path="/profile.jsp" />
<forward name="fail" path="/profile.jsp" />
</action>
```

**String parameter = mapping.getParameter();**

So in struts2 if i hit 
www.myweb.com/index/p=2
www.myweb.com/index/biz/name            /*here biz & name are 2 parameters*/
www.myweb.com/index/biz/name/23            /*here biz & name & 23 are parameters*/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcard patterns to pass the parameter.

```
<action name="/profile/*" class="net.viralpatel.struts.cleanurl.ProfileAction">
 <param name="id">{1}</param>
<result>
  <param name="location">/profile.jsp</param>
  <param name="id">{1}</param> 
</result>
 </action>
```

You can also use Named Parameter

```
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable"/>


@Namespace{"/users/{userID}");
public class ProfileAction exends ActionSupport {
private Long userID;
public void setUserID(Long userID) {...}
}
```

if the request URL is `/users/10/detail`, then the **ProfileAction** will be executed and its `userID` field will be set to **10**.

### Parameters after the action name

To use parameters in the URL, after the action name, make sure this is set:

```
 <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
 <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
```

Then the action mapping will look like:

```
 <package name="edit" extends="struts-default" namespace="/edit">
 <action name="/profile/*" class="net.viralpatel.struts.cleanurl.ProfileAction">
    <param name="id">{1}</param>
    <result>/profile.jsp</result>
 </action>   
 </package>
```

When a URL like `/edit/profile/123` is requested, **ProfileAction** will be called, and its "id" field will be set to **123**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the patternMatcher, wildcards are for doing something else.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

Using the REST plugin is another option, or the regex matcher, depending on your needs.